# Why my ASP.NET / SQL Server web app crashes when resumed after a period of inactivity?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wrote a simple query of a SQL Server database for my app. Multiple queries one after the other work fine. But if I leave the browser and the app active and do another query after a period of inactivity, the app crashes. It's not only slow; it actually crashes hard with the follwing error code:

*Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.*

What do I have to do in my code to prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: Who knows... No one has clairvoyance.

Comment: Until now, I thought "[It does not work](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html)" is the most detailed error message, I've ever got. Now it seems that "it actually crashes hard" just got my new favorite!

Comment: inspect the exception you get. most probably you will be able to fix it

Comment: How "hard" does it crash? Is the ASP.Net site completely unresponsive for other users until an app-pool recycle/iisreset/machine reboot/start of next millennium? Or does it just affect your session?

Comment: Not nearly enough information about what might go wrong...... do get you get an error?? If so, **what** error?? Have you checked the Windows event logs? Do they give you an idea of the problem??

Comment: I've just provided the error message. Thanks for pointing out the lack of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using sessions perhaps your session expired and when you revisit that is the error?

Can you please post the error you are recieving.

Also if you are executing the query directly are you properly closing your connection.  Its hard to say much more without better information like the exact error you get and how you define "crashing hard"

If its the MAC error I know what it is now. You are hosting in a shared hosting environment.  You will need to explicitly provide a MAC value in your web.config file.  The problem occurs because the belated request could be directed at a different server and there will be a mismatch between your application.

aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Comment: Folks, I will prepare the site and post the link so you can see the error for yourselves. It will take me a day or so because I am just a beginner: very slow to get things going.

Comment: I edited and provided the error msg in the original question so a test site is probably not necessary.